# Car loan and removing my ex from the loan?

Tags: united-states, loans, car

My ex and I bought a car a couple of years ago and we have not been together now for over a year and half.

I have the car and I make all the payments and now that I want to refinance and buy another car, I can't because he is still on the loan.

We have no contact with each other—it was an abusive relationship. I want to know if there is anything that I can do to get his name off the loan?

I also live in Oregon now and I think he is still in California, but we have no contact. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is his name also on the title?

Comment: yes his name is also on the title. I can not find him to sign anything over and the company we got the car from says they can't do anything with out his signature as well. i want to trade the car in and get a newer car. all my payments are up to date ect but without his signature they will not let me do anything. I have been married now also for a year and we can not locate my ex so we are stuck

Comment: That's a bummer.  You'll definitely need to talk to a lawyer.  Fortunately, there's Law.StackExchange.com... :)

Answer (score 6):

The bank should allow you to refinance the car and get a new loan in your name only.  I cannot think of a reason why you could not pay off the existing loan completely just because his name is also on the loan.

If his name is on the *title* as well, then it gets tougher.  If you can/don;t want to contact him to get a title release signed, then you'll probably have to file a lawsuit.  I would see if there's a local attorney that would handle this pro-bono or for a small fee.

Comment: if i file a lawn suit i have no idea how to go about doing that. do i have to do it in the state of Calif? or can if be done in Oregon?

Comment: Actually, I would first go to the tag office (or wherever you go in Oregon to register the title) and see if they can help - I bet they've dealt with the situation before. If they can't, I would talk to a local (Oregon) attorney.